# How to send checkboxes values from HTML to Node JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, checkbox

I tried to send some checkboxes values from HTML to Node JS. In my HTML file, I have some checkboxes in a table. I got the checked checkboxes values as following,

```
$("#createSS").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchIDs = $("#imgTable input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    console.log("selected::::" + searchIDs);
});
```

My HTML form is,

```
<form action="/addSlideShow" method="POST">
    <table id="imgTable" class="table">
        {{#images}}
            <tr>
                <td><input id={{imgURL}} type="checkbox" name="ch" value={{imgURL}}/></td>
            </tr>
        {{/images}}
    </table>

    <input id="createSS" type="submit" value="Create Slide Show" class="btn btn-success pull-left" disabled/>&nbsp;&nbsp;

</form>
```

In Node JS,

```
app.post('/addSlideShow', function (req, res) {
    var $ = req.body;
    $('td').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

When I'm clicking the button in HTML, the for isn't submit. How may I fix this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are not posting the data to the form url. As you have used `event.preventDefault()` which will never submit nor you used [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) to post data

Try to post the data using ajax like,

```
$("#createSS").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchIDs = $("#imgTable input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    console.log("selected::::" + searchIDs);
    $.ajax({
       url:'/addSlideShow',type:'post',
       data:{searchid:searchIDs},
       success:function(response){
          console.log(response);
       }
    });
});
```

In node js you will get,

```
app.post('/addSlideShow', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); //Output=> like { searchid: 'Array of checked checkbox' }
    console.log(req.body.searchid); // to get array of checked checkbox
});
```

Comment: by default my url is `http://dashboard.mybluemix.net/deletePage`. When I'm clicking the button it should be changed to `http://dashboard.mybluemix.net/addSlideShoe`. But it's not changing. I removed the `disable`. But button action is not triggering.

Comment: First clear. Do you want ajax or not? If not then why you change  `deletePage` to `addSlideShoe`

Comment: Well, if you `preventDefault()`, your form won't be sent as you ask it not to do what he should. By using that, you need to send your data to `/addSlideShoe` in some way or another, hence Ajax.

Comment: @codebot try my code then let us know what the next problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="createSS" type="submit" value="Create Slide Show" class="btn btn-success pull-left" disabled/>
```

Your submit button is disabled. Remove that `disabled` attribute right in the end.

Comment: No you don't, you just listen to event that never fires. Simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/v3a3xjvb/

Answer (score 0):

You are using `event.preventDefault()`, which tells the browser not to do what it should upon click. Remove that line and your form will be submitted. I'm not a Node ninja, but your data in req.body won't be in an html format. Querying $("td") is frontend logic. You need to assign a different name to each checkbox like `name="ch-{{$index}}"` (this would be like so in an angular ng-repeat). Or you should send `{searchid: searchIDs}` via ajax.